# SQL Stored proc

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, insert, stored-functions

I am trying to build a stored proc that pulls data from multiple tables and inserts it into the same table in the stored proc. Is that possible? So it is going to look something like,

```
Create Proc usp_abcd
Insert into table1 (clmn1, clmn2, clmn3)
from tableA
Insert into table1 (clmn1, clmn2, clmn3) 
from tableB
Insert into table1 (clmn1, clmn2, clmn3) 
from tableC
```

Comment: I hope it can be done with simple `JOIN` rather than a SP. Just explain a bit detail on tables.

Comment: It actually involves getting data from around 55 tables

Comment: If 55 tables is constant or it will increase/decrease, if so then you can you dynamic query. BTW are those tables are similar to each other?

Answer (score 0):

Yes...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_abcd()
BEGIN

INSERT INTO table1 (clmn1, clmn2, clmn3)
SELECT clmn1, clmn2, clmn3 FROM tableA
UNION 
SELECT clmn1, clmn2, clmn3 FROM tableB
UNION 
SELECT clmn1, clmn2, clmn3 FROM tableC;
```